# Add text over an image using SVG filter in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg-filters

I have this [implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/h9fjcrp7/) of blurred images:

HTML:

```
<img width="90" height="90" class="blurry" src="image.jpg">
<svg height="90" width="90" class="blurry">
    <image filter="url(#blur)" xlink:href="image.jpg" src="image.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" />
</svg>
<svg id="svg-blur-effect" style="display:none">
    <filter id="blur">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
img.blurry {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden; /* prevent image displaying non-blurry on IE10+ before browser can be detected */
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px); /* supported in newest webkit */
  -moz-filter: blur(10px); /* possible support for future versions */
  -o-filter: blur(10px); /* possible support for future versions */
  -ms-filter: blur(10px); /* IE10+ */
  filter: blur(10px); /* basic CSS3 definition */
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='10'); /* IE4 - 9; must be last otherwise it may be overriden by CSS blur filter */
}
svg.blurry {
  display:none;
}

.ie img.blurry { display: none; }
.ie svg.blurry { display: block; }
.blurry.visible { visibility: visible; }
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  if (-1 < navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')
   || -1 < navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/')
   || -1 < navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge/')) {
       $('body').addClass('ie');
   }
   $('.blurry').addClass('visible');
})
```

This is working in all browsers (Webkit, FF, IE9+). But now I need to **add an overlay with question mark (?) to each blurred image**.

---

First I tried to add it via `:after` CSS, but it does not work since it's not supported for images:

```
/* does not work */
.blurry:after { content: "?"; ... }
```

---

Then I tried to [add some HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/h9fjcrp7/) which works:

HTML:

```
<span class="img-wrapper">
  <img width="90" height="90" class="blurry" src="image.jpg">
  <svg height="90" width="90" class="blurry">
      <image filter="url(#blur)" xlink:href="image.jpg" src="image.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" />
  </svg>
  <span class="overlay"></span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper { display: block; float: left; position: relative; }
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent url('question_mark.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url('question_mark.png');
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url('question_mark.png');
  background-size: contain;
}
```

But I **don't want to change HTML** (neither through HTML nor JS) since these images are used on various pages and in various layouts and simply wrapping the image in a `DIV` or `SPAN` would most probably **break the layout** and need additional adjustments for each layout. *Adding only new properties to existing elements would be OK.*

---

So the question: **is there other way to add the overlay via CSS or SVG which is already used?**
Once more link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/h9fjcrp7/).

I've tried something like this, but did not find any way to make it work:

CSS:

```
.blurry { filter: blur(10px) url(question_mark.svg); }
.ie .blurry > image { filter: url(#blur) url(#question-mark); }
```

and HTML:

```
<img width="90" height="90" class="blurry" src="image.jpg">
<svg height="90" width="90" class="blurry">
    <image filter="url(#blur) url(#question-mark)" xlink:href="image.jpg" src="image.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" />
</svg>
<svg id="svg-blur-effect" style="display:none">
    <filter id="blur">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <text id="question-mark">?</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm sure a quick example would have been greatly appreciated. Whilst this is an old question it still appears as part of the top answer on Google when searching for this same question. An example or a relevant link would definitely be useful to new people coming here.